# Angular2 ngModel doesn't clear when set to ""

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Example class for storing my data

```
export class Key {
    value: any = '';

    formatter() {
        let value = MyFunction(this.value);

            if(!value) {
                value = '';
            }

            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

ngModel input field

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="key.value" (ngModelChange)="key.formatter()">
```

MyFunction() - Should remove all non-numeric characters from the string and return JUST the numbers

```
function MyFunction(mystr) {
   mystr = mystr.replace(/\D/g,'');

   if(mystr.length === 0) {
        return "";
   }else {
        return mystr;
   }
}
```

When MyFunction() returns an empty string and tries to update key.value...  Instead of clearing the input field it keeps appending the new letters.

Am I missing something?

Comment: could it be caching or something? try running your app in a different browser (firefox, chrome, IE).

Comment: Caching is completely disabled however I tried in different browsers and still no luck

Answer (score 0):

In `key.formatter()` function replace if condition with

```
if(value === ""){ 
    ... 
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of (ngModelChange) try using `[value]="key.value | yourCustomPipe`